# How do i run this java program from the command line of my windows computer?

Tags: java

Its on my desktop, if you could tell me step by step how i can run this program. I know javac compiles the program.

```
public class SimpleProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("A proverb");
        String Proverb  = "Practice makes perfect!";
        System.out.println("Proverb");
        int CharacterCount = Proverb.length();
        Syetem.out.println("The Proverb has "+CharacterCount + "Characters");
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many pointer about how to do this, including this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279542/how-to-execute-a-java-class-from-the-command-line or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864622/how-do-i-run-class-files-on-windows-from-command-line

Answer (score 1):

From the command prompt you can use Java command to run your class and follow it in the exact syntax as follows.

C:> java SimpleProgram

Answer (score 1):

[Running a Java Program from Command Prompt](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your program will *not* compile, as you posted it. Here is the version that will:

```java
public class SimpleProgram {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

      System.out.println( "A proverb:" );
      String proverb  = "Practice makes perfect!";
      System.out.println( "Proverb" );
      int characterCount = proverb.length();
      System.out.println( "The Proverb has " + characterCount + " Characters" );
    }
}
```

You can compile it and run as:

```sh
$ javac SimpleProgram.java 
$ java SimpleProgram
A proverb:
Proverb
The Proverb has 23 Characters
```

Comment: it wont run, it says $ javac SimpleProgram.java is not recognized as an external or internal command.

Comment: I just ran it in the example above. What you need to do is to install java, or if it is installed, you need to set some EVN variables ( JAVA_HOME, etc.. ). Check the [installation instructions](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/download_options.xml)

Answer (score 1):

To compile do java SimpleProgram

If you dont want to do this back and forth get [Textpad](http://www.textpad.com/)!

Answer (score 1):

Follow this step by step tutorial-
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5u8rFbpdvds