# Running java helloworld

Tags: java

I tried to google this, went to oracle.com and read all the questions on this forum related to this. I wrote a simple "Helloworld" program

```
package helloworld;

public class Helloworld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

NetBeans compiles the source code into a `.class` file. I move that file to `C:\MyJava`

I try to run it by `C:\MyJava> java -cp . Helloworld` and all possible variations of such. I keep getting the `NoClassDefFoundError: Helloworld (wrong name: helloworld/Helloworld)`.

To make sure. There's a question almost exactly like this (difference in "wrong name"). The solution to that question does not work in my case.

Comment: `package hello world` is an invalid package declaration, I assume you want `package hello.world;` instead.

Comment: @Thomas: Sorry that's my edit error.

Comment: C:\MyJava>cd helloworld then C:\MyJava\helloworld>java Helloworld .run it like this it will work where helloworld is your packagename.Copy the .class with package(folder).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the "wrong name" error because your class is in the package `helloworld`. Java expects you to provide the fully-qualified class name on the command line:

```
C:\MyJava> java -cp . helloworld.Helloworld
```

The directory structure must match the package structure. This means that you should have a directory `C:\MyJava\helloworld` that contains the class file `Helloworld.class`.

Comment: Jesper, thanks so much. I don't know if this was supposed to be obvious, but it sure wasn't to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You need to tell it the package name (which is `helloworld`):

```
C:\MyJava> java -cp . helloworld.Helloworld
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Lin. Your answer is right as well. Jesper added the package/folder structure that needs to be present to run java. Thanks.

Comment: you do not need to specify a classpath pointing to ".". This is default behaviour ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below post is similar to your problem. I hope it guides you;

[How do I run .class files on windows from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864622/how-do-i-run-class-files-on-windows-from-command-line)

Comment: This is not an answer. Use comments..oh you dont have enough rep for comments