# How to compile multiple class files in Java on LINUX shell?

Tags: java, linux, class, shell

Hello I am on campus trying to compile a simple binary tree program .. our campus only has shell and I am using Linux over eclipse..

I have 2 class files in my current directory bintree.java and treetest.java

```
javac bintree.java treetest.java
```

this code creates multiple classes but what is my next step? ive searched everywhere theres not a lot of info on java Linux shell. thank you

Comment: **What error do you get**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javac option to compile recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623161/javac-option-to-compile-recursively)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all of the java files you need to compile are in your directory you can

```
javac *.java
```

And then

```
java NameOfClassWithMainMethod
```

Otherwise if you want to learn to work without an IDE I would suggest learning to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/get-started). They will abstract away a lot of the tedium of compiling a project, and if become a pro dev you'll need to know at least Maven anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ find -name "*.java" > sources.txt
$ javac @sources.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You might look at http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-the-javac-command.html

When you run `javac xxx.java xxy.java xxz.java`  you should get several .class files as a result.  Is your problem really with running the javac or getting the resultant classes to run your program?

If so you may want to look here at another [stackoverflow questin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864622/how-do-i-run-class-files-on-windows-from-command-line)

Basically use  java -cp  classname for the class that has your "static Main()" in it

Comment: you are correct thank you for the help. however my program still does not run. I am on campus using a secure shell .. do you think its cuz im unable to reach the CLASSPATH correctly? I am seeing lots of info on CLASSPATH and I don't think mine is correct

Comment: If you are executing in the same directory you may not need a classpath argument

Comment: your help has been great thank you. godspeed friend.