# java command will not execute my .class file

Tags: java, console-application, command-prompt

I have two .class files that are in the same directory.

One is a class file containing a class I wrote that does not have a main function.  The other class file contains just the public static void main function that creates an object of my class and calls one function.

When I compile and run these within Netbeans IDE, it runs fine.  If I navigate to the .class files through the Windows Command prompt and try to run the files using the java command, I get an error saying it cain't find the main class.

Here's my class with the main function:

```
package a3;
public class mainTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A3 test = new A3();

          test.quiz();
    }
}
```

And my class with all of my methods is defined like so:

```
package a3;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class A3
{

    public void quiz()
    {
        // stuff
    }

    //more helper functions called from quiz function

} // end of class
```

When I try to run from the command prompt using:  java mainTest

I get:  Error: could not find or load main class mainTest
even though I'm staring at the mainTest.class file in the directory from which I'm using that command...  What am I missing here?

Also I should not that I'm able to launch other java applications with the same command, so I don't think it has anything to do with the environment variable.  It must be something with my code.

Comment: Your first class has an extra '}' in it.  Remove the extra '}' and try again.

Comment: Also, see if there is a classpath file that points to the class references being somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not sure how to find this.  There is a project.properties file within my Netbeans project, and I see some code within this file referring to classpath, but there are many different lines related to classpath - I'm not sure what any of these mean.

Comment: try using the -classpath or -cp option as outlined here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864622/how-do-i-run-class-files-on-windows-from-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run it from the directory outside of the a3 directory (the one that has the class files), execute this:

```
java a3.mainTest
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!  Is it because I have the package a3; code at the start?  If I delete this line of code, will I be able to simply run it from its directory?  Netbeans put this in by default.

Comment: @Sabien No, *you* defined a package called `a3` to NetBeans and put this class inside it. If you don't want it in a package, just move it to the default package, and NetBeans will fix the source. But classes should be in packages.

Comment: But I never wrote that line of code, package a3; - it was there when I created the project.  I'm not sure where it came from.  Regardless, now I know.

Comment: Most IDEs (like netbeans) want you to put your Java classes into a package, and they are a good practice to keep your project organized (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/). But it can be confusing until you get used to it.